# Strange characters inserted by Libreoffice when opening a .csv file and then saving it (on Linux)

Tags: csv, libreoffice

Here is what I did:

1. touch file.csv
2. Open this file in Libreoffice.
3. <s>Pasted a tabular text from the internet.</s>
4. Saved it in Libreoffice in Text csv format.
5. When I do the above, Libreoffice inserts 2 strange characters in the start of the file.

On googling I found that these are  \0's.

Here is what they look like:

```
cat file1.csv
```

��

My query is : How do I prevent Libreoffice from inserting these characters?

Note 1 : I skipped step 3 for this particular example.

Note 2 : I am doing this to create a CSV file from tabular data from the internet. I do not want the strange characters inserted in my CSV.

Comment: `$ od -t x1z file1.csv ` will tell more about those characters.

Answer (score 1):

> On googling I found that these are \0's.

That's a wrong way to come to a conclusion, because Google can't know what these characters actually are, as special characters get normalized for google search. Thus, the conclusion is probably wrong. Just because your terminal and/or text editor can't display a character and replaces it with something else doesn't mean it's a 0 byte.

OK, this is speculation, because you did not offer the actual file, just a *picture* of how your terminal (mis-)displays it.

But.

These two characters are probably the [Unicode 16 bit Byte-Order Mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16) characters, which libreoffice probably correctly inserted as you specified a unicode text encoding.

The proper question here is why your terminal can't deal with unicode. Get a better terminal emulator!

> How do I prevent Libreoffice from inserting these characters?

Two options:

- not at all; they're hurting no software that's not from the 90s, but make it unambiguous what the text encoding of your CSV is. Libreoffice automatically inserts them for Unicode, which is a good and appropriate thing to do.
- if you want the pain of needing to **explicitly** have to use the same encoding for all applications dealing with that CSV, use a non-unicode text encoding (The LibreOffice Calc "Export Text File" dialog you get when you save as CSV incorrectly calls that "Character Set"; it's not the set of character that gets specified, it's the way these are encoded as bits and bytes).

I very much recommend going option 1.

Comment: Many thanks. My problem is : when I read this  CSV in R, I have to explicitly say that the format is Unicode. If I do not, R is not able to parse it. However, as you suggested in ***option 2***, if I choose an encoding like Latin 3 (for example), then R can read it without any mention of the encoding. What do you advise?

Comment: Fix R is my recommendation, but I'm also the type for these kinds of fixes ;) no seriously, keep using Unicode, and tell R to use Unicode; this isn't the 90, and latin3 encoding breaks as soon as there is e.g. a single name with a special character not in Latin 3.  You technically would need to tell R about latin3 as well, otherwise it could not know what letter (Cyrillic, German Umlaut, Turkish I....) Is meant with anything non -ascii. R just happy accepts that breakage.